redis cluster subscriber is not working with lettuce
This is my code
 public void subscribeToEncounterCheckoutTimeChannel(){
       logger.info("Inside subscribeXXXChannel()");
       StatefulRedisClusterPubSubConnection<String, String> pubsubConnection = connectToRedisCluster.getClusterPubSubConnection();
       pubsubConnection.setNodeMessagePropagation(true);
       pubsubConnection.addListener(new RedisClusterPubSubAdapter(){

           public void message(String pattern, String channel, String message) {
               String msg = message;
               logger.info("msg" + msg);

           }
       });
       RedisClusterPubSubAsyncCommands<String, String> async = pubsubConnection.async();
       PubSubAsyncNodeSelection<String, String> masters =async.upstream();
       NodeSelectionPubSubAsyncCommands<String, String> commands = masters.commands();

       logger.info("number of master nodes: "+masters.size());
       commands.psubscribe("__keyspace@0__:"+CacheConstants.XXX+"*");
       logger.info(commands.toString());

    }

However, after entering the key and message, the system does not print any expiry messages.
I have tried to run the event information in individual nodes in a cluster with the following commands
`docker exec -it <ContainerID> sh 
redis-cli -c config set notify-keyspace-events  Kx
redis-cli -c
127.0.0.1:6379> CLUSTER NODES
127.0.0.1:6379> SETEX EncounterCheckoutTime:1 120 "Hello, Redis"
-> Redirected to slot [11230] located at 172.18.0.4:6379
OK
system changes the cluster host
172.18.0.4:6379> INFO keyspace
# Keyspace
db0:keys=1,expires=1,avg_ttl=9289'

found out the node in a cluster where the key got created and then run
`docker exec -it <ContainerID> sh 
redis-cli -c -h <IP of keyspace server>
psubscribe  '__keyspace@0__:EncounterCheckoutTime*'
or to subscribe keyspace and keyevents
psubscribe  '__key*__:*'`


I see the system is printing the expired key information.
$ redis-cli -c -h 172.18.0.4
172.18.0.4:6379> psubscribe  '__keyspace@0__:EncounterCheckoutTime*'
Reading messages... (press Ctrl-C to quit)
1) "psubscribe"
2) "__keyspace@0__:EncounterCheckoutTime*"
3) (integer) 1
1) "pmessage"
2) "__keyspace@0__:EncounterCheckoutTime*"
3) "__keyspace@0__:EncounterCheckoutTime:1"
4) "set"
1) "pmessage"
2) "__keyspace@0__:EncounterCheckoutTime*"
3) "__keyspace@0__:EncounterCheckoutTime:1"
4) "expire"


